# Understanding homology as a functor from $_R\mathbf{Comp}$ to $_R\textbf{Mod}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I have some trouble understanding the definition of homology. As the below figure says, $H_n$ is a functor for every $n\in\Bbb Z$. For example, $H_4$ is a functor from $_R\mathbf{Comp}$ to $_R\textbf{Mod}$. Since each object in $_R\mathbf{Comp}$ is a chain complex and a funtor maps each object in $_R\mathbf{Comp}$ to a corresponding object in $_R\textbf{Mod}$, then how does $H_4$ act on the  chain, say $\cdots\to C_n\to C_{n-1}\to C_{n-2}\to\cdots$?

[image]

Comment: It’s ignoring almost all other terms.

Comment: @Randall I can't quite get. Can you explain more?

Comment: if I have time later, yes.  Right now my kid is screaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$-th homology of a chain complex $(C_\bullet,d_\bullet)$ is defined as $$H_n(C_\bullet) = \ker d_n/\operatorname{im}d_{n+1}.$$

If $f\colon (C_\bullet,d_\bullet)\to (C'_\bullet,d'_\bullet)$ is a map of chain complexes (i.e. a collection of maps $\{f_n\colon C_n\to C'_n\}_n$ such that $f_{n-1}\circ d_n = d'_n\circ f_n$, for all $n$), then $H_nf\colon H_n(C_\bullet)\to H_n(C'_\bullet)$ is the map $$z_n+\operatorname{im} d_{n+1}\mapsto f_n(z_n)+\operatorname{im} d'_{n+1}.$$

Once you show that $H_nf$ is well defined and that $H_n$ respects compositions and identities, for each $n$ you have a well defined functor $H_n$ from the category of chain complexes to the category of modules.

Comment: Is the way the author stated the theorem problematic? I think the word "for each $n\in\Bbb Z$" is somehow weird.

Comment: @Eric, there is no problem, for every $n\in \mathbb Z$ there is a corresponding functor $H_n$. There are infinitely many of these functors.

Comment: Oh I see! I made some mistake. Thanks.